# Subtracting Values in Google Sheets With Multiple Conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am back with another question about this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNrJzSDpfTRuvZSRpt7BQn0HfA2mdhZzTym2DqNlXZU/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to have Column G automatically calculate the words I wrote in a given session. I could see this being done by looking for the project listed in column D, then if it's a short story, looking in column E to check the text, then finding the most recent total put in column F and subtracting that from the new total.

For example, if I put "Short Stories" in D24, "Perergia" in E24, and 1400 in F24, I want it to have 24 in G24 (since the last time I updated "Perergia" was in row 21, and the total then was 1376).

I've tried using IF() formulas but that didn't work, and being fairly new to spreadsheets (and mostly inexperienced with coding) I don't know of any other way to do this.

Feel free to poke around in the sheet listed above, as it is a copy and not the actual sheet I am using.

Answer (score 0):

=IFERROR(IF(E24<>"", F24-MAX(FILTER($F$2:$F23, $E$2:$E23=E24)), F24-MAX(FILTER($F$2:$F23, $D$2:$D23=D24))), F24)

Try this wherever you want your output to be. This will work for your current sheet, but unsure what sort of permutations you'll have in the future...

Comment: Hm...unfortunately that didn't work. I updated the copy, linked above, to show you the problem I'm having. It is outputting -1400 instead of the 24 it should be. I might play around with it a bit if it isn't figured out in the morning, but I'm off to bed for now. Thanks for the attempt, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Apologies, I had added a row as I could not get access to your sheet, I have rectified the answer